# Why do I get segmentation fault in the following code?

Tags: c

Nothing gets printed in my code. No compiler issue. Why doesn't it print anything? I get no warning either.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main() 
    { 
        struct site 
        { 
            int no_of_pages;
            char name[20];
        }; 
        struct site *ptr;
        ptr->no_of_pages = 665;
        printf("%d\n",ptr->no_of_pages); 

        char array[20];
        strcpy(array, "hello");
        strcpy(ptr->name, "Singularity");
        printf("%s\n",ptr->name);   
        return 0; 
}
```

Comment: (1) Enable compiler warnings and treat them as errors. If you are using gcc or clang, that's `-Wall -Werror`. With MSVC, at least `/W3 /WX`. Never compile anything without these options. (2) Get a good book on C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialise the pointer first

```
struct site *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct site));
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a warning which points out the root of your problem:

```
$ cc -Wall test.c 
test.c:13:5: warning: variable 'ptr' is uninitialized when used here
      [-Wuninitialized]
    ptr->no_of_pages = 665;
    ^~~
```